# Listar archivos en laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and i am using laravel 5.3.
I want to make a list of files but it throws me an error

```
Undefined variable: manzanas
```

**This is my controller index method:**

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $manzanas = manzanas::all(); 
        return View::make('manzanas.index')->with('manzanas', $manzanas);
       // return view('listarmanzana')->with(['manzanas' => $manzanas]);
    }
```

The Store method

```
public function crear_manzana(Request $request)
    {

        $manzanas = new manzanas;
        $manzanas->nombre=strtoupper( $request->nombre) ;
        $manzanas->direccion=strtoupper( $request->direccion) ;
        $manzanas->save();

    }
```

**My routes**

```
Route::resource('Manzanas','manzanasC');
    Route::post('crear_manzana', 'manzanasC@crear_manzana');
    Route::get('/listado_manzanas', 'manzanasC@index');
```

**The views**

```
@foreach ($manzanas as $manzana)
                        {{-- expr --}}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-5">
                          <!-- small box -->
                          <div class="small-box bg-red">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <h3>Manzana<sup style="font-size: 20px"> {{ $manzana->nombre }}</sup></h3>
                              <!-- <p>Unique Visitors</p> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                              <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">Ver / Administrar <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div><!-- ./col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                    @endforeach
```

**It give me this error in the view**

> 2/2  ErrorException in f50c18d5d13d3a1b9c5d1829238c99f00ebcad47.php
>   line 31: Undefined variable: manzanas (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\resources\views\manzanas\listarmanzana.blade.php)
>
> 1/2 ErrorException in f50c18d5d13d3a1b9c5d1829238c99f00ebcad47.php
>   line 31: Undefined variable: manzanas

**The line 31 is the line before the foreach**

Comment: Please keep in mind to write your question in English on Stack Overflow. If possible also translate any significant variable names. We all want to know what a "manzana" is now.

Comment: Hola Hilario. Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al inglés o sírvete postearla en https://es.stackoverflow.com . Hi Hilario, Welcome to SO, please translate your question to english [...].

Comment: @mario google says apple

Answer (score 0):

It may be the way you're passing the variable to the view, try this

```
return view('manzanas.index',['manzanas' => $manzanas]);
```